# Moq internal class and/or internal method

Tags: c#, moq, .net-4.6.1

On my project, I set:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("xyz")]
```

My unit tests work when my class and method are public.

```
public class MainController
{
    public virtual void RunForm()
    {
        ...
    }
```

If I change either to internal, my unit test fails. Is this a limitation of Moq?

```
var logger = new Mock<IExceptionLogger>();
var name = new Mock<MainController>
{
    CallBase = true
};
name.Setup(x => x.RunForm()).Throws(new Exception()));
name.Object.Init(logger.Object);
logger.Verify(m => m.LogError(It.IsAny<Exception>(), Times.Once);
```

Exception:

```
Test method Tests.Controllers.MainControllerTest.ExceptionsInitGetLoggedToAppInsights threw exception: 
    System.ArgumentException: Cannot set up MainController.RunForm because it is not accessible to the proxy generator used by Moq:
    Can not create proxy for method Void RunForm() because it or its declaring type is not accessible. Make it public, or internal and mark your assembly with [assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2")] attribute, because assembly Abc is not strong-named.
```

Comment: It should work, but instead of an assembly directive, you can set the setting in your `.csproj` file instead: https://www.meziantou.net/declaring-internalsvisibleto-in-the-csproj.htm

Comment: `mark your assembly with [assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2")] attribute`

Comment: @silkfire hmm same result with that

Comment: @devNull please post as answer, and I will accept. I saw that in a few places and thought, that just means that I have to put my assembly in the string. I didn't know that I needed it in addition to my own assembly.

Comment: could you provide your *{project}/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs* file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in the error message, you actually need to add the `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2")]` attribute to your assembly. `DynamicProxyGenAssembly2` is the assembly that Moq uses internally to create the proxy instances of your class to override/implement virtual/interface methods.